# Textbox value to URL Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, hyperlink

I would like to add a textbox value to my url so I am able to click on a button and open a clients record on the button click. I have tried the below as well as other methods but I am unable to get this working (the below is using a session but I have the client ID value stored in a textbox). Is there a way to do this please?

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Client_ID","~/ViewCustomers.aspx?id={0}") %>' />
```

Result should be ViewCustomers.aspx?id=2 for example.

I am using ASP.NET C# and using HTML 5 for the front end development.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the HyperLink a class and bind a javascript function to it.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="LinkWithID" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ride_id","~/ViewCustomers.aspx?id=") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then simply append the value of the TextBox to the url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.LinkWithID').click(function () {
        location.href = $(this).attr('href') + $(this).next('input').val();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```